# (Non) Context Free language?

Tags: automata

In an exam question it is asked to identify if the given language is Context-Free, Non Context Free or Regular.
This is the question :

[image: Question]

In my opinion this language is not a CFL since w doesn't belong to L', meaning that it belongs to not(L') which is all words (a^n b^n c^n) which is not CFL.

Apparently my answer is not right and I really don't understand why... Is this question a "trap" because i,j,k > 0 and not >= ? Meaning that a word (b^n c^n) is in L ? Looks like I'm lost !

I really need your help and explantions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to think of $L$ as having two parts.

- First part: $L_1$ is all strings *not* in the form $a^i b^j c^k$. We can write this with the regular expression $\neg [a^* b^* c^*]$, so it's regular.

  - (I've been informed this notation isn't universal, so to spell it out: it's the complement of the regular language $a^* b^* c^*$, and the complement of a regular language is regular.)
- Second part: $L_2$ is all strings in the form $a^i b^j c^k$ *such that the given conditions on $i, j, k$ are not fulfilled*.

The given conditions are that $i, j, k$ are all different. So how can those conditions be violated? Either $i=j$, or $j=k$, or $i=k$. We can call these three options $L_{2a}$, $L_{2b}$, and $L_{2c}$ if you want.

Let's take just one of them as an example; the others work the same way. $L_{2a}$ is *all strings of the form $a^i b^i c^k$*. Can you write a regular expression for this? How about a CFG? (The answers are no, and yes: in fact, this is one of the classic examples for what a CFG can do that a regular expression can't.)

Now, since $L_{2a}$, $L_{2b}$, and $L_{2c}$ are all context-free, their union ($L_2$) is also context-free. And since $L_1$ is regular, it's *also* context-free. So $L$, as the union of two context-free languages, is context-free.

Comment: Great, amazing answer, thanks a lot !

Comment: Really like the way you explained that

Comment: However, thinking about it, for the second part, it's eiter i = j or j = k or i = k OR i = j = k, meaning that there is also the form a^i b^i c^i which is not CFL. Making the union of those 4 sub options not especially a CLF.


Am I completely lost ?

Comment: @EliaDratwa You're right that $a^i b^i c^i$ isn't context-free. But $a^i b^i c^k$ is, and $a^i b^i c^i$ is a subset of that, so you don't have to care about it.

Answer (score -1):

Not L' isn't just all words a^nb^nc^n, it also contains words that don't fit the a^nb^mc^k pattern, like "cab" or "bac", etc. It also contains the words a^nb^nc^m, etc. Try writing a CFG for it.

Comment: Not really sure about that, moreover, words like cccaaabbb or bbaacc have to be recognize aswell... Maybe it's just me missing, don't understand something